# Root package.json unmet dependency in child package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

Lets say I have a Typescript project like so

```
root/
  api/
    package.json
  web/
    package.json
  ...
  package.json
```

In the root `package.json` I have the typescript dependency installed (this is to ensure it uses the same version in web & api).

If I install a package in **web/package.json** that has a `peerDepedency` on Typescript (lets say `ts-loader`) it will complain that Typescript is an unmet dependency.

**root package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^11.11.7",
    ...
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000"
  }
}
```

**web/package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6"
  }
}
```

How do I get around this without adding Typescript in the **web/package.json**?

If thats not possible, how do you ensure that the same version of packages is used across multiple modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately npm doesn't have any sort of package.json inheritance.

Since it's just a warning & everything should still work since node looks for `node_modules` in parent directories, I think you can do one of these:

- Just ignore the warning
- Move `ts-loader` up to parent directory
- Declare & install an exact version of typescript in each sub directory ([without any modifier](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)) and update them manually whenever necessary
- Switch to yarn & use [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) (I think you'd still have to list typescript in each package's dependencies, but at least they will be installed only once.)
- Use [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/), a js monorepo manager that can manage cross dependencies

Comment: Thanks! I really wanted to avoid using lerna/yarn but it seems to be the only proper solution.

Comment: yes, I wish npm was more capable in handling sub packages!

Comment: How does Lerna help?